# Firebase auth calls best practice for SPA w/ Flask backend

Tags: firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I am working on a modest SPA that (will) use Firebase for Authorization and Firestore for the DB and Flask on the backend (It's not strictly a true SPA because things like contact page, terms, etc are on different pages).  I have gone through tutorials such as [Firenotes doc tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine), and it looks like because it is a JWT instead of a session I have to authenticate with every request.

Question(s):

1. Is it considered best practice to validate on every request or should I log the user in and then store a session?
2. Even if I store the user in a session, I would still need to authenticate their JWT on any database call, so there is no uplift there is there?
3. Is there any concern about cloud costs with either approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase's own services:

1. Pass the ID token from the client to the server with every request,
2. Decode the token when they first receive it, and then
3. *Either* cache the decoded token *or* cache the key pair that was used to decode it, since that step is most time-consuming.

So while there may be other approaches to accomplish your use-case, I'd say the above is quite tried and proven.